# Finding eigenfrequencies for a matrix

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

I have a square matrix of size 8*8. Some of terms are a function of frequency(omega). I want to write a function which searches for eigenfrequencies in a given range like (0 - 1kHz).

I have included the function below. Here the terms 'tx', 'ki1', 'ki2' are function of omega. For finding eigenfrequencies, the determinant of matrix should be zero. But I can't find determinant of matrix if all values are not given.

Basically, I don't want to give a frequency and then get eigenvalues.
I want the matrix to be solved to give eigenvalues which will be eigenfrequencies.

Can you please suggest any method or function for that?

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

```
import numpy as np 

def mat(l1,l2,omega1):
    kmat = np.zeros((8,8), dtype = complex)
    
    ki1 = omega1 / c1 
    ki2 = omega1 / c2
    tx = 1 + n * np.exp( -1j * omega1 *tau)       
    
    kmat[0][0] = -1
    kmat[0][1] = 1 
   
    kmat[1][0] = - np.exp(- 1j * ki1 * l1) # simple duct  
    kmat[1][2] = 1 
    kmat[2][1] = - np.exp( 1j * ki1 * l1)
    kmat[2][3] = 1     
    
    kmat[3][2] = tx  # velocity coupling 
    kmat[3][3] = -tx
    kmat[3][4] = -1
    kmat[3][5] = 1
    
    kmat[4][2] = 1
    kmat[4][3] = -1
    kmat[4][4] = -1
    kmat[4][5] = -1
    
    kmat[5][4] = - np.exp(- 1j * ki2 * l2)
    kmat[5][6] = 1
    kmat[6][5] = - np.exp( 1j * ki2 * l2)
    kmat[6][7] = 1    
    
    kmat[7][6] = -1
    kmat[7][7] = -1
    
    return kmat
```

Comment: Once you calculate the function of omega and poke it into the matrix, the matrix becomes indistinguishable from a matrix of constant terms.

Comment: Yes, correct. That is my problem. I don't know how to solve such matrix for finding eigenfrequencies.

Comment: `np.linalg.eigvals`

Answer (score 0):

Why not do sort of bootstrapping to estimate the eigenvalues?
For each repetition fill the elements in the matrix which are not constant with f(omega) and find the eigenvalues. then sort them from largest to smallest
If the distribution of eigenvalues stays more or less the same across the repetitions - you have a fair enough estimate.

Comment: Are you looking for np.linalg.eigvals?

Answer (score 0):

You don't say which project you are looking at the documentation for but sympy can do this:

```
In [1]: omega = Symbol('omega')

In [2]: M = Matrix([[1, omega], [omega, 1]])

In [3]: M
Out[3]: 
⎡1  ω⎤
⎢    ⎥
⎣ω  1⎦

In [4]: M.eigenvals()
Out[4]: {1 - ω: 1, ω + 1: 1}
```

However you need to bear in mind that for a matrix larger than 4x4 with symbolic entries it is not always possible to obtain a "closed form" expression for the eigenvalues due to the Abel-Ruffini theorem:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem